# JQuery : hover doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem trying to use JQuery.

Here's the code I would like to make work on my page :

http://jsfiddle.net/ktz0f6st/

But it doesn't work on my page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.timeline').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
        }, function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'cyan');
        });
    });
</script>

<section id="eduandwork" style="top:20%; bottom:20%; height:100%; width:100%; text-align:center;">
    <div class="container hidden-xs">
        <ul class="timeline">
            <li class="timeline-inverted">
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                        <h5 class="timeline-title"><br><br>IT MANAGEMENT BACHELOR</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <p>2014 - 2019</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is my code.

EDIT : By saying it doesn't work, I mean when I hover the element, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: it works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/c0rrjcka/

Comment: Define *it doesn't work*

Comment: It worked in JSFiddle on Chrome

Comment: Hi guys, it def works on jsfiddle but not on my own web page, i think the problem is the way i call Jquery in the Script tag but i can not find it

Comment: Hi LcSalaza, by doesn't work i mean when i hover the element, it doesn't do anything

Comment: Yassin Hajaj Check my solution. I found your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script tag should look like those below:
Here is your answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.timeline').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'cyan');
    });
});
</script>

<section id="eduandwork" style="top:20%; bottom:20%; height:100%; width:100%; text-align:center;">
    <div class="container hidden-xs">
        <ul class="timeline">
            <li class="timeline-inverted">
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                        <h5 class="timeline-title"><br><br>IT MANAGEMENT BACHELOR</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <p>2014 - 2019</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the suggestion, i know you can do it with CSS but the main question here is, why doesn't it work with JQuery on my own page when it does on jsfiddle.. i'm kinda frustrated actually

Comment: @YassinHajaj Check my latest suggestion.

Comment: I'm sorry but it stil does not work, i tried the css on the elements and it works fine but JS is not cooperating

Comment: @YassinHajaj no just copy and paste my answer.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Glad to help. Would be thrilled if you'd vote for my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your Jquery call add in an end script tag, then start a new one.

In your initial script call you specify a source "src='blah'". If you run your code inline on the page in a second script or in your page's files it will run successfully.

If you call jquery first, then run a second script with your code, your hover works just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/mPawlak/heczLkxd/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.timeline').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'cyan');
    });
});
```

Comment: oops, didn't refresh. 1" beat me to it.